# Are the rings $\mathbb{Z}_2[X] /(X^2 + 1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I'm struggling with the question.  I know how to demonstrate that $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2 +1) \cong \mathbb{C}$ and similarly $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2 +2) \cong \mathbb{C}$.  However I cannot come up with an understanding of the ring, or any candidate homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^2 +1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

I cannot figure out how to map the products.

What functions should I try testing?

Comment: $X^2+1=(X+1)^2$ for $X\in\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: which is to say, that would be a zero divisor, right?

Comment: Please tell us what is $\Bbb Z_2$, the field with two elements or the $2$-adic integers... ?!

Comment: If $\Bbb Z_2$ is the field with two elements $F=\Bbb F_2$, then we have $$F[X]/(X^2+1)=F[X]/(X+1)^2\cong F[Y]/Y^2$$(via $X=Y+1$ and $Y=X+1$), then note that the elements in $F[Y]/Y^2$ are of the shape $a+bY$ and we may write the isomorphism to the ring $\Bbb Z/4$ of integers modulo $4$ by mapping $0\to 0$, $1\to 1$, $Y\to 2$, $Y+1\to2+1=3$.

Comment: @dan_fulea In $\mathbb{F}_2[Y] / Y^2$, $1 + 1 = 0$ which doesn't hold in $\mathbb{Z} / 4$.

Comment: I haven't encountered 2-adic integers yet.  Sounds interesting!

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes, it was typed after excluding the ring structure in the OP, looked good for a second, but after that i could not edit... Of course an error, thanks for pointing to it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of $K= \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ are $0,1,x,1+x$. As $(x+1)^2= x^2+1$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$,  we get that $y^2=0$ in $K$ for $y=x+1$.

While no non zero elements of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ have a square equal to zero.

So the rings can’t be isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you.  It makes sense that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has no zero-divisors but $(x+1)(x+1) = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ *does* have non-zero zero divisors, but it doesn't have an element $y\ne0$ such that $y^2=0$ the way $\mathbb Z_2[X]/(X^2+1)$ does

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Does a product of fields have nonzero nilpotent elements?

Comment: I had to look up nilpotent. It is now clear from the above examples that $(x+1)^2 = 0$ and there is no mapping that preserves this.